# Disable auto-vectorization of specific loops in a function in GCC

Tags: gcc, auto-vectorization

I want to turn off auto-vectorization for specific loops in a function.  How can I do this with GCC?  I know I can turn auto-vectorization off for the whole function with `__attribute__((optimize("no-tree-vectorize")))` but how do I do this for individual loops in a function (with MSVC I can use add `#pragma loop(no_vector)`).

```
void dot_int(int * __restrict a, int * __restrict b, int * __restrict c) { 
    for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) {        
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    //#pragma loop(no_vector)  //don't vectorize this loop
    for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) {        
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to do that?

Comment: I'm trying to separate the vectorized loop into the vectorized and non-vectorzied part.  The way it is now I can only get one.  I tried using separate inline functions but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone cares I came up with a solution. It's really the inverse. Rather than disabling auto-vectorization for certain loops it only enables it for certain loops.

To do this compile with `-O2` and use `#pragma omp simd` like this.

```
void dot_int(int * __restrict a, int * __restrict b, int * __restrict c) {
    #pragma omp simd 
    for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) {        
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) {        
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
}
```

Thought the vectorization of `#pragma omp simd` does not necessarily generate the same code as vectorization with `-O3`.